# PCI SATA Controller Card Locking Up at Boot

Tags: sata, pci

So I have the following setup -

ASUS M2N4-SLI Motherboard with AMD Chip of some kind with 4 GB Dims 2 CD/DVD ROM Drives
  1 320 GB SATA Drive containing the CentOS Operating System and 2 250 GB SATA Drives which
  are mirrored in software RAID1 and mounted to the filesystem.

The issue I am having is this - I would like to add 2 more drives and configure them for RAID1 just like the 2 I have in there now, only the problem is all the drives I own are SATA drives and my motherboard SATA controller only has 4 ports.  So, thinking the solution must be simple, I go down to Frys and purchase a "SABRENT" '4 Port SATA PCI Host Controller Card'.  I plug it in and boot up.  No issues.  Bear in mind I think this card is pretty cheap, it only cost me 25 bucks - and I have yet to install the "drivers" as I can see the motherboard already sees the card and when I check using CentOS utility I can see the card there too.

Now when I attach the two new drives to the PCI Controller ports, I go through the motherboard's boot up screen, I see the PCI card's 'RAID' utility option like I did the first time, and then suddenly I see printed on the screen the following information:

"2 ST31000528AS"

Which I assume are the drives I've attached via SATA cables to the PCI Controller card - problem is that's it, I don't get any farther than that - I am not able to progress past this point to the normal boot up screen that the CentOS normally shows me, etc, etc.

Anyone have any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS and set the boot controller to be the onboard SATA controller versus the add-in card.

Comment: Check the boot ROM of the controller you've added. Maybe an `F8` when the new SATA controller begins to initialize?